# Почему breadcrumb не выводится на главной странице?

Tags: php, woocommerce

Подскажите, почему на всех страницах хлебные крошки нормально показываются, а на главной странице они не показываются?
Главная страница магазина выбрана в настройках "Настройки -> Чтение -> Главная страница -> Новая главная страница". Для этой страницы  "Новая главная страница" я задал новый шаблон, в котором вверху указано, как:
Template Name: New template
В этом шаблоне **New template** конечно есть такой код, отвечающий за подключение breadcrumb:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' ); ?>
```

но как говорилось, breadcrumb на главной странице не выводится почему-то.
И подскажите пожалуйста в похожей теме моей, связанной с этой [Шаблон страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637745/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)

Comment: Если этот вопрос задать Гуглу, то все стремятся, наоборот, убрать хлебные крошки с главной страницы. Для многих логически мыслящих людей на главной странице breadcrumb является нонсенсом, поскольку этот элемент предназначен для ориентации пользователя и удобной навигации на более высокие уровни сайта - а выше главной страницы уровня никакого нет.

Comment: labris, а что по второй теме?